# Casting Datatypes SQL DataFrames

Tags: python, casting, schema, sqldatatypes

I am trying to read in a dataframe to an RDD in databricks but have have not been able to determine why the program is reading my integer columns as string.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

masterRowsRDD = masterRDD.map(lambda l: Row(playerID=l[0], birthYear=int(l[1]), birthMonth=int(l[2]), birthDay=int(l[3]), birthCountry=l[4], birthState=l[5], birthCity=l[6], deathYear=int(l[7]), deathMonth=int(l[8]), deathDay=int(l[9]), deathCountry=l[10], deathState=l[11], deathCity=l[12], nameFirst=l[13], nameLast=l[14], nameGiven=l[15], weight=int(l[16]), height=int(l[17]), bats=l[18], throws=l[19], debut=date(l[20]), finalGame=date(l[21]), retroID=l[22], bbrefID=l[23]))
```

I have tried casting the datatype directly the field (see above) and also tried to allow python to interpret the datatype (see below).

```
masterRowsRDD = masterRDD.map(lambda l: Row(playerID=l[0], birthYear=l[1], birthMonth=l[2], birthDay=l[3], birthCountry=l[4], birthState=l[5], birthCity=l[6], deathYear=l[7], deathMonth=l[8], deathDay=l[9], deathCountry=l[10], deathState=l[11], deathCity=l[12], nameFirst=l[13], nameLast=l[14], nameGiven=l[15], weight=l[16], height=l[17], bats=l[18], throws=l[19], debut=date(l[20]), finalGame=date(l[21]), retroID=l[22], bbrefID=l[23]))
```

I made a Schema below to validate the items I brought into the MasterRowsRDD. This validates that the data type is cast correctly.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType, StringType, DateType
masterSchema = StructType( [\
                            StructField('playerID', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('birthYear', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('birthMonth', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('birthDay', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('birthCountry', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('birthState', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('birthCity', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('deathYear', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('deathMonth', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('deathDay', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('deathCountry', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('deathState', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('deathCity', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('nameFirst', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('nameLast', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('nameGiven', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('weight', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('height', LongType(), True), \
                            StructField('bats', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('throws', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('debut', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('finalGame', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('retroID', StringType(), True), \
                            StructField('bbrefID', StringType(), True), \

                            ])

# Making DF
masterDF = spark.createDataFrame(masterRowsRDD, masterSchema)
# print(masterDF.rdd.collect())
masterDF.show()
masterDF.printSchema()
```

This is the error that shows when I run the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 48.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 48.0 (TID 121) (ip-10-172-222-3.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'birthMonth'', from , line 8. Full traceback below:*